# confluence create a link of a page to another page name?

Tags: emacs, confluence

I am using Confluence via Emacs confluence-mode, and I would like to give my pages a meaningful name, but then also give them a short name that would make it faster to type when editing. Can I create a page that is just a link to another page with a different name?

For example, create a page called `My meaningful name for this page` and then create a link to that page called `p1` that is simply a pointer to the other page. When opening `p1`, it would actually be opening the other page.

Essentially, I want to be able to open the page:

http://my-confluence.mydomain.com/display/MySpace/p1

And end up with:

http://my-confluence.mydomain.com/display/MySpace/My+meaningful+name+for+this+page

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a redirect. On your p1 page, throw this inside an html macro:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href("http://My meaningful name for this page.com");
</script>
```

That will automatically redirect to the correct page. Only downside is it might visibly show the p1 page for a fraction of a second. If it does, and that is unacceptable, I would refer you to this answer on Atlassian's forums:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/124121/how-to-properly-redirect-pages-in-confluence

It lists 2 plug-ins, one of which I use, which do it very seamlessly. They're not free though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your use-case a bit more? You can achieve this by using anchors (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Working+with+Anchors) if you're linking to the same page. If you need to link to a new page, this might help:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+Shortcut+Links